# Quantmod viewFinancials to data.frames across multiple lists of getFinancials

Tags: r, quantmod

Where am I going wrong here...

I am trying to create a `data.frame` of a number of `symbols`from the `quantmod`package

When I run the following;

```
library(quantmod)
symbols <- c("HOG", "GE", "GOOG")
symbols.f <- sapply(symbols, function(x) { paste0(x, ".f") })
symbols <- sub("\\.f","", symbols.f)

for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {   
 getFinancials(symbols[i], src="yahoo", auto.assign = TRUE)
}
```

I get a list of 3 stock symbols financial data.

When I run;

```
GE <- as.data.frame(viewFinancials(GE.f))
```

I am able to save the 4 years worth of data as a `data.frame` but when I try to do it for all `symbols` I run into an error. (Ideally I would like to combine the loop functions to create the `data.frame`´s

```
for(j in 1:length(symbols)) {
  viewFinancials(symbols.f[j])
}
```

Comment: In one case you made an assignment. In the second case you didn't.